# Prove that: $\frac{ab}{a+b}+\frac{bc}{b+c}+\frac{ac}{a+c}\leq \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that: $$\frac{ab}{a+b}+\frac{bc}{b+c}+\frac{ac}{a+c}\leq \frac{a+b+c}{2} : (a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^+$$

Comment: If $a = b = c = 1$ then you have the equation $\frac {1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$ which is true. And since $1$ is the smallest positive real number, this statement must be true. The LHS is only greater than the RHS when $a \neq b \neq c$

Comment: No, 1 IS NOT the smallest positive real number...

Comment: Then what is$?$ $0?$ Oh wait crap...I AM SUCH A NOOB

Comment: Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1745413/42969 – Both found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bab%7D%7Ba%2Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bbc%7D%7Bb%2Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bac%7D%7Ba%2Bc%7D%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%2Bb%2Bc%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality is true because $\frac{ab}{a+b}\leq\frac{a+b}{4}$.

Comment: This problem is an exact translation  from a persian mathematical book!!

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi I think there is a some typo in this book.

Comment: You're right, thank you.Also the proof of the reverse is easy

Comment: Do you suggest me to correct it?

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi Yes, of course, you can fix it.